# Use a single external jar in multiple runnable jars

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have multiple runnable jar files. Each of these jar files references the same external jar file. When I try to export my runnable jar files individually with eclipse, each export creates a directory e.g. jar1_lib, jar2_lib. Each of these directories contains the same referenced jar file.

I want to have each of my runnable jar files reference a single directory which contains a single instance of the required external jar.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it is possible, but you will need to update source code of all projects which use this single jar file.

Consider [JCL Framework](https://github.com/kamranzafar/JCL/)

Below, there's sample code from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450837/784540)

```
JarClassLoader jcl = new JarClassLoader();  
jcl.add("myjar.jar"); //Load jar file  
jcl.add(new URL("http://myserver.com/myjar.jar")); //Load jar from a URL  
jcl.add(new FileInputStream("myotherjar.jar")); //Load jar file from stream  
jcl.add("myclassfolder/"); //Load class folder  
jcl.add("myjarlib/"); //Recursively load all jar files in the folder/sub-folder(s)  

JclObjectFactory factory = JclObjectFactory.getInstance();  

//Create object of loaded class  
Object obj = factory.create(jcl,"mypackage.MyClass");
```